# How to change font source url from local to CDN?

Tags: magento2, css, cdn, fonts, ultimo

I have uploaded google fonts on the local server to a custom directory and it seems to work well so far except that the Ultimo theme I am using is picking the base URL to generate font URL path. Ideally, the theme should pick the static content URL when CDN is enabled. I believe this requires few changes in the below file where I could either hardcode the CDN URL or make changes so that the theme uses CDN static content URL to generate a font URL path.

```
<?php

namespace Infortis\Base\Helper;

use Infortis\Base\Helper\Data as HelperData;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Fonts extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * Custom font directory path, relative to: /app/design/frontend/Infortis/<theme_name>/web/
     */
    const CUSTOM_FONTS_DIR = 'fonts/custom/';

    /**
     * Quotation mark for complex font family names (e.g. containing whitespace)
     */
    const QUOTE = "'";

    /**
     * Main helper of the theme
     *
     * @var HelperData
     */
    protected $theme;

    /**
     * Asset repository
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository
     */
    protected $assetRepo;

    /**
     * Logger
     *
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * Supported file extensions
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $supportedExtensions = ['eot', 'woff2', 'woff', 'ttf', 'otf', 'svg'];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $valueGoogleFontsString;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $valueLocalFontsString;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $valueFontStacksString;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Repository $assetRepo,
        HelperData $helper
    ) {
        $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
        $this->theme = $helper;
        $this->_logger = $context->getLogger();

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize font strings
     *
     * @param string
     * @param string
     * @param string
     */
    public function initFontStrings($valueGoogleFontsString, $valueLocalFontsString, $valueFontStacksString)
    {
        $this->valueGoogleFontsString = $valueGoogleFontsString;
        $this->valueLocalFontsString = $valueLocalFontsString;
        $this->valueFontStacksString = $valueFontStacksString;
    }

    /**
     * Get raw URL string with google fonts defined by user
     *
     * @param string $storeCode
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getGoogleFontsString($storeCode = null)
    {
        if ($this->valueGoogleFontsString === null)
        {
            $this->valueGoogleFontsString = $this->theme->getCfgDesign('defined_fonts/google_fonts_string', $storeCode);
        }

        // Clear the string: remove whitespaces and unneeded quote characters
        $this->valueGoogleFontsString = trim($this->valueGoogleFontsString);
        $this->valueGoogleFontsString = trim($this->valueGoogleFontsString, "'\"");

        return $this->valueGoogleFontsString;
    }

    /**
     * Get raw string with names of custom local fonts defined by user
     *
     * @param string $storeCode
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getLocalFontsString($storeCode = null)
    {
        if ($this->valueLocalFontsString === null)
        {
            $this->valueLocalFontsString = $this->theme->getCfgDesign('defined_fonts/local_fonts_string', $storeCode);
        }

        // Clear the string: remove whitespaces
        $this->valueLocalFontsString = trim($this->valueLocalFontsString);

        return $this->valueLocalFontsString;
    }

    /**
     * Get raw string with font stacks defined by user
     *
     * @param string $storeCode
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getFontStacksString($storeCode = null)
    {
        if ($this->valueFontStacksString === null)
        {
            $this->valueFontStacksString = $this->theme->getCfgDesign('defined_fonts/font_stacks_string', $storeCode);
        }

        // Clear the string: remove whitespaces
        $this->valueFontStacksString = trim($this->valueFontStacksString);

        return $this->valueFontStacksString;
    }

    /**
     * Get fallback font stack for body font
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFallbackFontStack()
    {
        // Clear the string: remove whitespaces
        return trim($this->theme->getCfgDesign('font/fallback_body_font_stack'));
    }

    /**
     * Get final URL string with google fonts to load
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGoogleFontsFinalUrl()
    {
        $url = $this->getGoogleFontsString();

        // Remove https protocol name
        $count = 0;
        $pattern = "https:";
        $url = preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($pattern) . '/', '', $url, -1, $count);

        // If protocol name not found, search for http
        if ($count === 0)
        {
            $pattern2 = "http:";
            $url = preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($pattern2) . '/', '', $url, -1);
        }

        return $url;
    }

    /**
     * Get array with custom local fonts defined by user.
     * Array contains values for the "font-face" CSS at-rule:
     * - 'font-family': font family name
     * - 'src': resource containing the font data
     *
     * @param string $storeCode
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLocalFontsFontface($storeCode = null)
    {
        $fontfaceProperties = [];

        $fontNames = $this->getLocalFontsFamilies(false, $storeCode); // Get font names (don't remove file extensions)
        if (empty($fontNames))
        {
            return $fontfaceProperties;
        }

        foreach ($fontNames as $name)
        {
            // Important: don't remove file extensions before calling generateFontfaceSource(...)
            $src = $this->generateFontfaceSource($name);

            // Prepare font name: trim quotes (before removing extension), remove extension, add quotes if needed
            $name = trim($name, "'\"");
            $name = $this->removeFileExtension($name);
            $name = $this->quoteIfNeeded($name);

            if ($src)
            {
                $fontfaceProperties[] = ['font-family' => $name, 'src' => $src];
            }
        }

        return $fontfaceProperties;
    }

    /**
     * Generate "src" property for "font-face" CSS at-rule which specifies
     * the resource containing the font data.
     *
     * @param string $fontName
     * @return string
     */
    protected function generateFontfaceSource($fontName)
    {
        // Trim quotes
        $fontName = trim($fontName, "'\"");

        // Check if the font name contains a file extension
        $origExt = pathinfo($fontName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($origExt)
        {
            $fontName = pathinfo($fontName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extensions = [strtolower($origExt)];
        }
        else
        {
            $extensions = $this->supportedExtensions;
        }

        // Loop through all extensions and build "src" property
        $result = "src:";
        $resultForEotType = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($extensions as $ext)
        {
            // Asset path
            $fontPath = self::CUSTOM_FONTS_DIR . $this->convertFontNameToFileName($fontName) . '.' . $ext;

            // Try to create asset
            try
            {
                $asset = $this->assetRepo->createAsset($fontPath);
                $fontUrl = $asset->getUrl();
                $sourceAsset = $asset->getSourceFile();
            }
            catch(\Exception $e)
            {
                // The source file does not exist so the asset also does not exist
                $fontUrl = null;
            }

            // Check if asset exists
            if ($fontUrl)
            {
                if ($ext === 'eot')
                {
                    $resultForEotType = "src: url('{$fontUrl}');";
                    $result .= " url('{$fontUrl}') format('embedded-opentype'),";
                }
                elseif ($ext === 'woff2')
                {
                    $result .= " url('{$fontUrl}') format('woff2'),";
                }
                elseif ($ext === 'woff')
                {
                    $result .= " url('{$fontUrl}') format('woff'),";
                }
                elseif ($ext === 'ttf')
                {
                    $result .= " url('{$fontUrl}') format('truetype'),";
                }
                elseif ($ext === 'otf')
                {
                    $result .= " url('{$fontUrl}') format('opentype'),";
                }
                elseif ($ext === 'svg')
                {
                    $result .= " url('{$fontUrl}') format('svg'),";
                }

                $i++;
            }
        }

        // If at least one asset exists
        if ($i)
        {
            $result = rtrim($result, ', '); // Remove the last occurrence of the comma
            $result .= ";\n"; // Add final semicolon

            if ($resultForEotType)
            {
                $result = $resultForEotType . "\n" . $result;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If no asset exists, erase the initial value of $result
            $result = '';

            $this->_logger->info(
                "No font file available for font {$fontName}."
                . "Make sure to upload font file to the proper folder, set correct file permissions, deploy static files and flush the cache."
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get names of Google fonts defined by user
     *
     * @param string $storeCode
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getGoogleFontsFamilies($storeCode = null)
    {
        $finalFontNames = [];

        // Get URL string with defined fonts. The string can look like in this example:
        // https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,600,700|PT+Sans+Narrow|Roboto:300,300i,400&amp;subset=greek,latin-ext
        $fontStringRaw = $this->getGoogleFontsString($storeCode);
        if (empty($fontStringRaw))
        {
            return $finalFontNames;
        }

        // Get string starting from 'family=' and remove that start
        $fontStringRaw = strstr($fontStringRaw, 'family=');
        $fontStringRaw = str_replace('family=', '', $fontStringRaw);

        // If string contains '&'
        if (strpos($fontStringRaw, '&') !== false)
        {
            // Get definition of font families, omit definition of script subsets.
            // Retrieve the part of the string before the first occurrence of '&'.
            $fontStringRaw = strstr($fontStringRaw, '&', true);
        }

        // Get array of font definitions (strings) from the string
        // At this stage, the string looks like this: Open+Sans:400,400i,600,700|PT+Sans+Narrow|Roboto:300,300i,400
        $fontStringsArray = explode('|', $fontStringRaw);

        // Create list of font names
        foreach ($fontStringsArray as $fontString)
        {
            $exploded = explode(':', $fontString);

            // After the explode, $exploded[0] contains font name, $exploded[1] contains font styles and weights.
            // Convert font name to readable version, for example: Open+Sans => Open Sans.
            $rawFontName = $exploded[0];
            $count = 0;
            $fontName = str_replace('+', ' ', $rawFontName, $count);

            // If the number of replacements performed is greater than zero, font name will be quoted
            if ($count > 0)
            {
                $fontName = self::QUOTE . $fontName . self::QUOTE;
            }

            // Font string not always has definition of styles and weights, so the array not always has element [1].
            // If it has, list the styles.
            if (isset($exploded[1]))
            {
                $fontName = $fontName . '  (available: ';
                foreach (explode(',', $exploded[1]) as $style)
                {
                    // If style is italic
                    $end = strstr($style, 'i');
                    if ($end === 'i' || $end === 'italic')
                    {
                        $style = str_replace($end, '', $style);
                        $fontName .= $style . ' italic' . ', ';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $fontName .= $style . ', ';
                    }
                }
                $fontName = rtrim($fontName, ', '); // Remove the last occurrence of the comma
                $fontName .= ')';
            }
            // else
            // {
            //     $fontName = $fontName . '  (available: 400)';
            // }

            $finalFontNames[] = $fontName;
        }

        return $finalFontNames;
    }

    /**
     * Get names of custom local fonts defined by user
     *
     * @param bool $removeExtension
     * @param string $storeCode
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getLocalFontsFamilies($removeExtension = false, $storeCode = null)
    {
        $finalFontNames = [];

        // Get string with names defined by user. The string can look like in this example:
        // Ubuntu-Medium; Montserrat; Sun Valley; My Font.svg; 'Weston Free'
        $fontStringRaw = $this->getLocalFontsString($storeCode);
        if (empty($fontStringRaw))
        {
            return $finalFontNames;
        }

        // Create list of font names
        foreach (explode(';', $fontStringRaw) as $fontName)
        {
            // Trim whitespaces
            $fontName = trim($fontName);

            // Trim quotes added by user
            $fontName = trim($fontName, "'\"");

            // Check if font name contains a file extension and remove it
            if ($removeExtension)
            {
                $fontName = $this->removeFileExtension($fontName);
            }

            // Add quotes if needed
            $fontName = $this->quoteIfNeeded($fontName);

            $finalFontNames[] = $fontName;
        }

        return $finalFontNames;
    }

    /**
     * Get font stacks defined by user
     *
     * @param string $storeCode
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCustomFontStacks($storeCode = null)
    {
        $finalFontNames = [];

        // Get string with font stacks defined by user
        $fontStringRaw = $this->getFontStacksString($storeCode);
        if (empty($fontStringRaw))
        {
            return $finalFontNames;
        }

        // Create list of font names
        foreach (explode(';', $fontStringRaw) as $fontName)
        {
            // Trim whitespaces and quotes
            $fontName = trim($fontName);
            $finalFontNames[] = $fontName;
        }

        return $finalFontNames;
    }

    /**
     * Remove file extension from font name
     *
     * @param string $fontName
     * @return string
     */
    protected function removeFileExtension($fontName)
    {
        // Remove extension
        $origExt = pathinfo($fontName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($origExt)
        {
            $fontName = pathinfo($fontName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        }

        return $fontName;
    }

    /**
     * Add quotes to font name
     *
     * @param string $fontName
     * @return string
     */
    protected function quoteIfNeeded($fontName)
    {
        // If font name contains space, it will be quoted
        if (strpos($fontName, ' ') !== false)
        {
            $fontName = self::QUOTE . $fontName . self::QUOTE;
        }

        // If font name contains hyphen, it will be quoted
        if (strpos($fontName, '-') !== false)
        {
            $fontName = self::QUOTE . $fontName . self::QUOTE;
        }

        return $fontName;
    }

    /**
     * Convert font name to file name
     *
     * @param string $fontName
     * @return string
     */
    protected function convertFontNameToFileName($fontName)
    {
        // Trim whitespaces and quotes, replace spaces with hyphen
        $fontName = trim($fontName);
        $fontName = trim($fontName, "'\"");
        $fontName = str_replace(' ', '-', $fontName);

        return $fontName;
    }

    /**
     * Remove additional info in parentheses
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function removeAdditionalFontInfo($name)
    {
        // Remove text in parentheses
        $name = preg_replace('/\(.*\)/', '', $name);
        return trim($name);
    }

    /**
     * Get names of fonts defined by user
     *
     * @param string $storeCode
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDefinedFontFamilies($storeCode = null)
    {
        $finalFontNames = [];

        $googleFontsNames = $this->getGoogleFontsFamilies($storeCode);
        $localFontsNames = $this->getLocalFontsFamilies(true, $storeCode); // Remove file extensions from local font names
        $fontStacks = $this->getCustomFontStacks($storeCode);
        $finalFontNames = array_merge($googleFontsNames, $localFontsNames, $fontStacks);

        return $finalFontNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear, please explain

Comment: what part of the question is not clear?

Comment: What you exactly want? You can change fount url from header XML file or less file. Why you are doing code for that.

Comment: I want to serve google fonts via CDN.

Comment: You can simply add them in your default_head_view.xml file

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the font file from the CDN through XML, but [there's a bug in Magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2228) that makes you escape the ampersand three times before it works.

Here's the XML code you for instance put in `Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,500,600&amp;amp;amp;subset=latin-ext" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

This bug is fixed in the upcoming release 2.3.4 so when you run >=2.3.4 you can do this;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:200,300,400,500,600&amp;subset=latin-ext" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Below are the CDN URLs of two fonts. How can I inject them? Even if I inject them how can I tell my theme not to use system fallback fonts and use these URLs.

https://d2e2haje5duf32.cloudfront.net/static/version1571730518/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/en_US/fonts/custom/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff2

https://d2e2haje5duf32.cloudfront.net/static/version1571730518/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/en_US/fonts/custom/open-sans-v17-latin-600.woff2

Comment: Also the goal is to avoid serving assets from local server. Below Ultimo theme setup 

https://monosnap.com/file/AawQHEtyCkkg1IFPae5iKToLnB4QjL

https://monosnap.com/file/AnQUDyXdemY8kKQQ6eIcPa2rb7kbTO